# Reloading Sinatra page based on time interval

Tags: ruby, variables, sinatra, refresh

I have a value stored in a variable called value. Value is being run in a background task that makes it go up by one every second or so.
Now, I have

```
    get '/' do
    "#{value}"
    end
```

How can I either reload this page every 10 seconds, or just refresh it so it shows the new value of value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">` into html head

Comment: This is ok for quick fix/test. But for real big project consider using some javascript library in conjunction with websockets/server-sent-events/http-polling, because reloading the whole page is often time and resource consuming.